# Sort query results by HTML table column

Tags: php, javascript, html, sorting

I'm looking for a more **efficient**, **elegant** and **secure** way to sort data displayed inside an HTML table. This is what I've come up with so far and it looks somewhat bloated / noobish.

I also thought of something like storing the sorting in a `$_SESSION` so I don't have to carry the currently selected order over to the next page "manually" within the URL. Maybe a "safe&simple" piece of JavaScript+PHP (but no frameworks please) would make sense? My thoughts go in circles for hours now.

```
<?php
$ro_arr = array(
    "kid" => "kid",
    "kwd" => "Keyword",
    "cpc" => "ApproximateCPC",
    "cmp" => "Competition",
    "mov" => "MonthlyValue",
    "gms" => "GlobalMonthlySearches",
    "lms" => "LocalMonthlySearches",
    "dfc" => "KeywordDifficulty",
    "com" => "com",
    "net" => "net",
    "org" => "org",
    );

if (!empty($_GET['ro']) && strlen($_GET['ro']) == 7 && array_key_exists($col = substr($_GET['ro'], 0, 3), $ro_arr)) {
    $dir = (substr($_GET['ro'], 4, 3) == 'asc' ? "ASC" : "DESC");
    $res_order = $res_arr[''. $col .''] ." ". $dir;

} else {
    $_GET['ro'] = "kid_asc";
    $res_order = "kid ASC";
}
?>

<!-- just for testing -->
<pre><?php echo $res_order; ?></pre>
<!-- done testing -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='kwd_asc')?"kwd_dsc":"kwd_asc"; ?>">Keyword</a></td>
    <td><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='cmp_dsc')?"cmp_asc":"cmp_dsc"; ?>">Comp.</a></td>
    <td><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='cpc_dsc')?"cpc_asc":"cpc_dsc"; ?>">Ad CPC</a></td>
    <td><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='mov_dsc')?"mov_asc":"mov_dsc"; ?>">Value</a></td>
    <td><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='gms_dsc')?"gms_asc":"gms_dsc"; ?>">Global Searches</a></td>
    <td><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='lms_dsc')?"lms_asc":"lms_dsc"; ?>">Local Searches</a></td>
    <td><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='dfc_asc')?"dfc_dsc":"dfc_asc"; ?>">Difficulty</a></td>
    <td width="22"><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='com_dsc')?"com_asc":"com_dsc"; ?>">com</a></td>
    <td width="22"><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='net_dsc')?"net_asc":"net_dsc"; ?>">net</a></td>
    <td width="22"><a href="sort.v1.php?ro=<?php echo ($_GET['ro']=='org_dsc')?"org_asc":"org_dsc"; ?>">org</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use the "http://www.datatables.net/" for sorting in Client Side which is very fast rather than using in Server Side

Comment: @Venkat, shame that link is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of code to almost a half if you'll use two parameters instead of one:

1. The parameter by which you're sorting: kid, com, net, org...
2. Order: asc, dsc

Comment: TY. I thought about that too, but I'd have to use an exception for kwd_* and dfc_* I guess. These two are supposed be ordered ASC by default, whereas it's the opposite with the others.

Comment: @nimmneun I don't understand how the default behavior should be affected when you split the variables

Comment: what I meant is that - if the last selected sorting direction is ASC, all table headers will show DESC unless I add an exception for kwd_* and dfc_*. I previously did split up COLUMN and ORDER with `explode("_", $_GET['ro'])`to keep the URL more clean, but moved on to what I currently have.

Comment: @nimmneun it sounds like something that can be easily fixed by replacing the order for the two exceptions, it doesn't require duplicating the whole thing.

Comment: ok, after working on something different for a bit ... your suggestion was applied within a minute =) I was probably suffering from severe temporary blindness earlier. The updated code is ~400 Bytes lighter now. TY =)

Answer (score 0):

If your table isn't too large and you're not adverse to using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), use [tablsorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Once you get into the thousands of rows, client side sorting can get a little unwiledy.

Comment: TY. ATM I only use 10k rows for testing purposes and am still in the 0.002-0.005s execution time range. But "kid" is set to unsigned mediumint already, which will hopefully be enough. Do you have any experiences with jQuery+tablesorter how if/how it effects scaling?

Comment: @nimmneun Client side sorting realy does depend somewhat on the amound of data returned. I've notice slowdown on one of my projects at aroun 2k rows. It may change for you. Best way to find out if it is suitable is to download it and try it. Table sorter can be very quick to apply so you have nothing to lose by giving it a try. Also once you get to table of that size, ask yourself, how useful or user friendly a dataset of that size is.

Comment: @ JonP + Venkat, you both convinced me to have a more indepht look at client side result processing. Depending on the set filters, the number of results actually returned will usually be in the low 100s or below. Since I want to preserve the ability not only to filter, but also load additional results dynamically `onKeyUp()` I will probably have to dig deeper into client side processing first I guess.